# reading content of master database at a different server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query for example

```
select * from sys.databases
select * from sys.configurations
```

I believe this information is stored at master database.
I would like to have a look at configuration settings in the past.

Can I restore msdb/master databases at different server as regular user databases and make sense of those mentioned queries?

Looks like `select * from restored_master.sys.databases` just ignores current database. I know an option to replace `master/msdb` using startup parameters - that should work, but a bit longer option and need compatible version of server.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I restore msdb/master databases at different server as regular user databases and make sense of those mentioned queries?

Couple of options you can use without restoring system database :

1. **GUI - Registered Servers**

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]
2. [**PowerShell**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/let-powershell-do-an-inventory-of-your-servers/)

Comment: Kin, my goal is to restore msdb / master from the past and find "previous" settings. So reading via a linked server does not solve my problem.

Comment: Thats an overkill - restoring msdb / master from previous backups. **What are you trying to achieve ?** You can use [default trace](http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/09/14/configuration-changes-history-in-sql-server/) or [configure recording and alerting on any config change](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2364/capturing-and-alerting-on-sql-server-configuration-changes/). Config changes should not happen often and they should be tested and agreed with stakeholders.

Comment: I'm trying to view settings in the past from using a weekly backup. I would like to see value that was on the sql server a week ago.